# How to get position of cursor in notepad

Tags: vb.net

I need to get to current location/coordinates of the cursor on the screen in another application using VB.NET 2010.  For instance, how would I get the current cursor position in notepad or MS Word?

Comment: Cursor coordinates in another program?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this is impossible for Notepad.
For Word it could be possible, if this Interop Modell exposes this information.
If the text is selected in word, you can use the selection object to find the Information you need.

Answer (score 0):

This will set a variable to cursors position.

```
    Dim MousePosition As Point
    MousePosition = Cursor.Position
```

Then you can use this variable where you want to

Comment: I need cursor of blinking key cursor as in ms. word, notepad. not the cursor of mouse... Please help me..